# arrange text below image

Tags: html, css

I want to have option buttons to have image and text below image. Right now i have managed to have image but dont know how to arrange text exactly below image without disturbing alignment.

```
  <div>
   <label>
     <input type="radio" name="fb" value="small" />
     <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20/35d/fff&text=f">

    </label>

    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="fb" value="big" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/40x60/35d/fff&text=f">
     </label>

     <label>
       <input id="fb3" type="radio" name="fb" value="med" />
       <img src="http://cache1.asset-cache.net/gc/120523070-dogs-gods-gettyimages.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=de2%2btiBrzaNEk9d4xwzh%2fvq8qyKYRsuWlpI1%2f65dmsaBkiniqNTDJkrq7zrUnaC6">
      </label>


      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="fb" value="small1" text="ss" />
          <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20/35d/fff&text=f" text="sdsdsd">

        </label>

        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="fb" value="big1" />
           <img src="http://placehold.it/40x60/35d/fff&text=f">
        </label>

        <label>
          <input id="fb3" type="radio" name="fb" value="med1" />
          <img src="http://cache1.asset-cache.net/gc/120523070-dogs-gods-gettyimages.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=de2%2btiBrzaNEk9d4xwzh%2fvq8qyKYRsuWlpI1%2f65dmsaBkiniqNTDJkrq7zrUnaC6">
         </label>
        </div>
```

Here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grjxq8rr/7/) .

I am looking for output something like below

[image]

Also wish to generate option button in rows and column dynamically. Any idea related on how to achieve it?

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/grjxq8rr/7/

Comment: With gap https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/grjxq8rr/9/

Comment: This is what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/grjxq8rr/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this css to the page:

```
<Style>
label{
  float:left;
  height:100px;/*can be modified*/
 padding:10px;/*can be modified*/
width:50px;

}
</Style>
```

and after every image add 
 and then the name as below:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/20x20/35d/fff&text=f"><br/>
 My name
```

To control how many images per row there is two ways.

1 - adding div for clear:

```
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
```

2- add everything inside a div and adjust the width of this div to until your reach to the proper count of images.

add this to the main div that you have

```
<div id="maincontainer" style="width:100px">
```

I updated the css by adding width:50px which means every label will be 50px... the main container is 100 => 2 items / row.

make the width of maincontainer to 150 -> 3 item / row....

Comment: how can i build this option button dynamically in 3*2 format.. 3 options in 1 row and 3 in 2nd row

Comment: its all about controlling the width of the container... ill update the code

Comment: the text is not center aligned

Comment: you really need some HTML/css courses :)....  add 
     text-align:center; to the css

Comment: Really sorry... was being lazy... i will try your solution in my script and test it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111498/discussion-between-happy-and-sufyan-jabr).

Comment: when i have bigger text then i would like to wrap word https://jsfiddle.net/grjxq8rr/21/

Comment: if you can help on wrapping word then would be thankful to you.i have tried work-break but doesnt work

Comment: Just add "*/" to close the comment in the css @ height:100px;/*can be modified*/

Answer (score 2):

Just set the to display: block;

```
.figures span, .figures img {
display: block;
}
```

you can write as

```
<label>
      <input type="radio" name="fb" value="big1" />
       <img src="http://placehold.it/40x60/35d/fff&text=f">
       <span>your text</span>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your need, you can get desired output by using `<br/>` tag or without 
 tag.

**With <br /> Tag**

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grjxq8rr/7/)

**Without <br /> Tag**

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/grjxq8rr/9/)

In fiddle 1 i have used <br / > tag and in second i have used `display:block;` on images and `display:inline-block` on label. So use whatever you are ok with :)

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your images inside a `<figure>` tag and use `<figcaption>` for your text below it. I'm not sure what you mean in regards to "option buttons" though.

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/KzJOyY

```
<figure>
  <img src="image-src-url" alt="">
  <figcaption>Dog</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: how can i build this option button dynamically in 3*2 format.. 3 options in 1 row and 3 in 2nd row

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS with this:

```
label > input + img {
      /* IMAGE STYLES */
      cursor: pointer;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
       margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      float: left;
    }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Harpreet_devgun/grjxq8rr/10/)